Failed to publish topic to pubsub
We have upgraded spring boot version to 3.0.0 and jdk to 17 and trying to publish topic to pubsub but giving following below issues:-
c.g.c.s.p.c.p.PubSubPublisherTemplate    : Publishing to projects/gcp-ushi-shared-security-npe/topics/isg-lws-carbon-auth-logging topic failed.
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I was trying to publish pubsub topic and generate logs in Splunk. For the same, I upgraded the spring boot versions. Any versions above 2.5 doesn't work but 2.2 version works fine in publishing topic to pubsub.

I have also tried with updating certs to truststore as well as cacerts. Dint help

Hi @Lakshmi Ganeshan, Could you provide the code that you are using and the official documentation if you are following any ?

Hi Dhiraj, Thank you for the reply. It's a huge code. Is there any way to contact you in whatsapp/ some alternative? very badly struch with the issue from past 4-5 weeks after upgradation. It's a big code and several files are present. Not sure how to post here. Please help

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Thank you, Dhiraj. Have opened a new issue on the issue tracker with my issues and sent the whole project zipped. Please help
